# CFDOCUMENT in Lucee page too big

Tags: pdf-generation, lucee, cfdocument

I have a dynamically  generated page with css page breaks between sections of code. When I load the page in my browser, it displays fine. When I use the browser PRINT menu, I can SAVE AS PDF and set my scale to 49% and everything fits on my page just fine with .25in margins all around.

I'm trying to make it possible for the PDF to just pop up in the browser window and let the viewer of the page be prompted with  a download SAVE AS dialog instead of using the browser default print menu. If they use CHROME it is different than if they use FIREFOX as the print dialog is not the same. Firefox works easy enough but I'd rather avoid any browser print menu using the SAVE AS PDF function.

I'm using the  tag and when the page loads with that wrapped around, it blows up everything to like 10 times it's needed size (not sure what proportion but my header logo that is normally only 150px wide is like almost one entire page of the pdf.

How do I scale the output of the CFDOCUMENT to 49% where I know the browsers print options make it fit a LETTER size page just fine?

I used the  tag in Lucee since it does not allow the CFHTMLTOPDF tag.